# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=-1 Al rotar el dispositivo por segunda vez

Tags: android

mi problema es que este error me aparece al rotar la pantalla por segunda vez, los fragments no se pierden cuando hago rotacion del dispositivo por primera vez pero al hacerlo por segunda, automaticamente me tira este error, no sé que puede estar pasando, agradecería mucho su ayuda.
Dejo el onCreate de mi Actividad

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true);

    concederPermisos();
    //preguntar si es tablet
    esTablet=getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.es_tablet);
    mBundle=new Bundle();
    mBundle.putBoolean("es_tablet",esTablet);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();



    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    //Asignacion Fragment Manager
    miFragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
    //Toast

    //Mostrando el primer fragment

    if (esTablet==false){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }else{
        //Si es una tablet de siete pulgadas bloqueará la rotación de pantalla, los únicos con este privilegio serán las de diez pulgadas.
        if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.es_tablet_de_7_pul)==true){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1f);
        findViewById(R.id.content_main).setLayoutParams(params);

    }

    if (savedInstanceState==null){
        main=new MainFragment();
        main.setArguments(mBundle);
        miFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, main,"fragment_main").commit();

        //dialogs
        miFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.alphem_container,new AlphemFragment()).commit();
    }
    //dialog salir
    salirDialog=new Dialog(this);
    salirDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_salir);
    salirDialog.findViewById(R.id.salir_no).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            salirDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    salirDialog.findViewById(R.id.salir_si).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            salirDialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });


}

  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.es_tablet)==true){

        Bundle Test=outState;

        ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> listasFragment= (ArrayList<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();


        getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"fragment_main",getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_main"));
        getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"datos_fragment",getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("datos_fragment"));
    }


}
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(inState);

    if (esTablet==true){
        mBundle=new Bundle();
        mBundle.putBoolean("es_tablet",esTablet);
        main = getFragmentManager().getFragment(inState,"fragment_main");


        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(main);

    }
}
```

Y el LogCat del error

> 03-08 01:46:00.557 8355-8355/com.alphemsoft.education.regression 
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.alphemsoft.education.regression, PID: 8355
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alphemsoft.education.regression/com.alphemsoft.education.regression.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=-1
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>
> **Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=-1**
>       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
>       at android.app.BackStackState.instantiate(BackStackRecord.java:147)
>       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1832)
>       at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:933)
>       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread.onCreate(BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread.java:54)
>       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:319)
>       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
>       at com.alphemsoft.education.regression.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

La linea 69 es exactamente el super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) del onCreate, por favor, agradeceria su ayuda, ya no sé que más hacer.

Comment: Tu error puede estar aquí: `getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"fragment_main",getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_main"));`
`getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"datos_fragment",getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("datos_fragment"));`

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿Por favor pordría decirme cual es el error? no logro comprenderlo.

Comment: Usas `android:configChanges ` en tu manifesto?

Comment: @StefanNolde No, solo uno que no pertenece a la actividad, sino a AdMob **<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />**

Comment: Te dejé una respuesta basado en una sospecha que tengo sobre la secuencia de acciones en la reconstrucción de actividades con cambios de configuración. Si eso no te soluciona el problema, te recomiendo poner `Log.d(...)` comentarios en `onCreate`, `onSaveInstanceState`, `onRestoreInstanceState` y `onDestroy` para revisar en la depuración por donde la app pasa antes de caerse.